# How to add class for td in datatable when add row runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, bootstrap-4

I want add class to td when get list data by ajax

> Default my code html

```
<tr>
                    <td>@fisrt.System_Code.Code</td>
                    <td>@fisrt.System_Code.Caption</td>
                    <td class="text-success">@string.Format("{0:N0}", maden)</td>
                    <td class="text-danger">@string.Format("{0:N0}", den)</td>
                    <td class="text-warning nrt-bd" dir="ltr">@string.Format("{0:N0}", maden - den)</td>
                </tr>
```

> When i want get list data after filtering , i dont know how to add class

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Record_Professor/Search_Budget/',
                data: { from: from, to: to },
                success: function (results) {
                    results.forEach(function (item) {
                        $('#table_id').dataTable().fnAddData([
                            item.Code,
                            item.Caption,
                            item.Maden,
                            item.Daeen,
                            item.Balance
                        ]);
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('error; ' + eval(error));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"className": "Classname",** is  used to add class at run time

```js
$('#table_id').DataTable({
  data: data2,
  "autoWidth": false,
  deferRender: true,
  pageLength: 10,
  responsive: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  select: {
    style: 'os',
    selector: 'td:first-child'
  },
  "lengthMenu": [
    [10, 25, 50, -1],
    [10, 25, 50, "All"]
  ],
  "columnDefs": [{
    "className": "Classname",
    "targets": [5,2,3,4,9,]
  }]
});
```

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { className: "my_class", "targets": [ 3 ] }
  ]
} );
```

Comment: Sorry Not Work :(

Comment: what is columnDefs ? how to select column 3 ?